# Keeping data up to date in Ruby and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, update-attributes

I have a MySQL database that has a table that stores data from a third party payment provider service. The data we store is primarily subscription details for customers. Unfortunately I need to download an export file and parse it to get the data. What I want to do is set up a daily job that updates the subscription end_dates in my database. So say I have a subscription object that looks like this:

```
Subscription object:
  attributes:
    id: 
    subscription_uuid: 
    account_code: 
    email: 
    current_period_ends_at:
```

What I want to know is the most efficient way to update these objects current_period_ends_at datetime field in mysql using rails.

I am starting with an array of hashes that looks like this:

```
[{:id => 1, :subscription_uuid => 123, :account_code => 10, :email => test@test.com, :current_period_ends_at => 2013-10-02 16:37:05}]
```

I was thinking I would iterate through the array in batches, since it is a large amount of data, and call the rails update_attributes method on each subscription object in the database. I am wondering how smarter people would do this or if there is a way I could retrieve in batches a bunch of the subscription objects and then also update them in batches to make the process faster?

Answer (score 0):

I would use create! which generates an object and saves it. create also accepts an array of hashes in order to create and save multiple objects. Your intuition as to batching is correct.

```
  params = {
    :id     => something,
    :subscription_uuid => something,
    :account_code   => something,
    :email      => something,
    :current_period_ends_at => something
  }
  Subscription.create!(params)
```